# How to rotate div around itself using css3?

Tags: css

I am trying to implement rotation for all the divs inside my website. I need this functionality on mouse hover.

Comment: Are you tried yet? Please add your code snippet along with the code.

Comment: "rotation for all divs" can mean a number of things and without a code example it's impossible to answer your question. if you could provide some code, and more importantly what you're expected outcome is, you will definitely find help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

div:hover {
  
  animation: rotate 1s forwards alternate linear
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to make it with transition so you need to add to the main class the following:

```
transition:all 0.3s;
```

note: the `0.3s` represents the time, you can change it to any number like `0.7s`

then you will add the following to the `:hover` event

```
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
-o-transform:rotate(90deg);
transform:rotate(90deg);
```

note: `deg` is representing how many degrees you want them to rotate, so you can add any number rather than `90deg` like `360deg`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle for you check that out so, you get the ideas how rotation works.

```css
div{
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color:#000;
margin:50px;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover{
    transform:rotate(45deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); 
      -0-transform:rotate(45deg);
 }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```